# How to get Descendants in a nested XML with namespaces using Linq

Tags: .net, linq

I'm having trouble navigating this complex xml schema to get the descendants of the vw_Misc_AllData tag. I thought I could just navigate directly to the tag section I needed, but it doesn't work correctly. Could someone review my .Net Fiddle and maybe let me know what's wrong?

```
        using System;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Xml.Linq;

        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                    string xml = @"<getMiscDataResult xmlns='http://tempuri.org/WSMisc/Service1'> 
                                    <xs:schema id='DataSetMisc' targetNamespace='http://www.tempuri.org/DataSetMisc.xsd' xmlns:mstns='http://www.tempuri.org/DataSetMisc.xsd' xmlns='http://www.tempuri.org/DataSetMisc.xsd' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata' attributeFormDefault='qualified' elementFormDefault='qualified'> 
                                        <xs:element name='DataSetMisc' msdata:IsDataSet='true' msdata:Locale='en-US' msdata:EnforceConstraints='False'> 
                                            <xs:complexType> 
                                                <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'> 
                                                    <xs:element name='vw_Misc_AllData'> 
                                                        <xs:complexType> 
                                                            <xs:sequence> 
                                                            </xs:sequence> 
                                                        </xs:complexType> 
                                                    </xs:element> 
                                                </xs:choice> 
                                            </xs:complexType> 
                                        </xs:element> 
                                    </xs:schema> 
                                    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata' xmlns:diffgr='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1'> 
                                        <DataSetMisc xmlns='http://www.tempuri.org/DataSetMisc.xsd'> 
                                            <vw_Misc_AllData diffgr:id='vw_Misc_AllData1' msdata:rowOrder='0'> 
                                                <TEST_KEY>12345</TEST_KEY> 
                                            </vw_Misc_AllData>
                                            <vw_Misc_AllData diffgr:id='vw_Misc_AllData1' msdata:rowOrder='0'> 
                                                <TEST_KEY>12345</TEST_KEY> 
                                            </vw_Misc_AllData>
                                        </DataSetMisc>
                                    </diffgr:diffgram>
                                </getMiscDataResult>
                            ";

                            XDocument elements = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                            XNamespace ns = "http://www.tempuri.org/DataSetMisc.xsd";
                            var data = from d in elements.Descendants(ns + "DataSetMisc").Descendants("vw_Misc_AllData")
                                select new
                                {
                                    testKey = (string) d.Element("TEST_KEY").Value
                                };

                            foreach ( var element in data )
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine( element.testKey );
                            }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is passing all descendant or element queries a name space like you did in first level.

```
    var data =
        from d in elements.Descendants(ns + "DataSetMisc")
        .Descendants(ns + "vw_Misc_AllData") 
         select new
        {
            testKey = (string)d.Element(ns + "TEST_KEY").Value
        };
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/90Rzwc)

Comment: Cool thanks!  I also noticed I don't even need the Descendants(ns + "DataSetMisc") using just the Descendants(ns + "vw_Misc_AllData") works fine as long as I add the ns directive in the Element(). Thanks for helping.